# Как просто вывести поле из базы

Tags: laravel

Как вывести значение поля отношения в Laravel

```
$base = Base::find(1);
$base->contracts->total;
```

**total** это поле в таблице **contracts**

Получаю ошибку **Property [total] does not exist on this collection instance.**

Comment: а связи в модели точно прописаны? И правильно?

Comment: Да все прописано и правильно 100 % , через tinker получаю корректно

Comment: @Федотов если `total`это поля в таблице `contracts` и если ваш модель `Base` имеет множество `contracts` тогда вы можете вывести значение поле `total` в цикле или таким образом `$base->contracts()->first()->total`

Comment: @Федотов в тексте ошибки все очень ясно описано. На крайний случай пользуйся `dump()`.